# Spark ClassCastException cannot assign instance of FiniteDuration to field RpcTimeout.duration on Scala 2.10.5

Tags: java, scala, apache-spark

I am facing this exception when I try to submit a job. What to try? JAR is compiled on Scala 2.10.5 and uses

kafka_2.10-0.8.2.0.jar ,

kafka-clients-0.8.2.0.jar

Here is the full stack trace of the exception

> java.lang.ClassCastException: cannot assign instance of scala.concurrent.duration.FiniteDuration to field org.apache.spark.rpc.RpcTimeout.duration of type scala.concurrent.duration.FiniteDuration in instance of org.apache.spark.rpc.RpcTimeout
>       at java.io.ObjectStreamClass$FieldReflector.setObjFieldValues(ObjectStreamClass.java:2133) ~[na:1.8.0_74]
>       at java.io.ObjectStreamClass.setObjFieldValues(ObjectStreamClass.java:1305) ~[na:1.8.0_74]
>       at java.io.ObjectInputStream.defaultReadFields(ObjectInputStream.java:2006) ~[na:1.8.0_74]
>       at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readSerialData(ObjectInputStream.java:1924) ~[na:1.8.0_74]
>       at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readOrdinaryObject(ObjectInputStream.java:1801) ~[na:1.8.0_74]
>       at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject0(ObjectInputStream.java:1351) ~[na:1.8.0_74]
>       at java.io.ObjectInputStream.defaultReadFields(ObjectInputStream.java:2000) ~[na:1.8.0_74]
>       at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readSerialData(ObjectInputStream.java:1924) ~[na:1.8.0_74]
>       at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readOrdinaryObject(ObjectInputStream.java:1801) ~[na:1.8.0_74]
>       at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject0(ObjectInputStream.java:1351) ~[na:1.8.0_74]
>       at java.io.ObjectInputStream.defaultReadFields(ObjectInputStream.java:2000) ~[na:1.8.0_74]
>       at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readSerialData(ObjectInputStream.java:1924) ~[na:1.8.0_74]
>       at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readOrdinaryObject(ObjectInputStream.java:1801) ~[na:1.8.0_74]
>       at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject0(ObjectInputStream.java:1351) ~[na:1.8.0_74]
>       at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject(ObjectInputStream.java:371) ~[na:1.8.0_74]
>       at org.apache.spark.serializer.JavaDeserializationStream.readObject(JavaSerializer.scala:76) ~[spark-core_2.10-1.6.0-cdh5.12.0.jar:1.6.0-cdh5.12.0]
>       at org.apache.spark.serializer.JavaSerializerInstance.deserialize(JavaSerializer.scala:109) ~[spark-core_2.10-1.6.0-cdh5.12.0.jar:1.6.0-cdh5.12.0]
>       at org.apache.spark.rpc.netty.NettyRpcEnv$$anonfun$deserialize$1$$anonfun$apply$1.apply(NettyRpcEnv.scala:261) ~[spark-core_2.10-1.6.0-cdh5.12.0.jar:1.6.0-cdh5.12.0]
>       at scala.util.DynamicVariable.withValue(DynamicVariable.scala:57) ~[correctedViewershipUserProfile-1.14-SNAPSHOT-jar-with-dependencies.jar:na]
>       at org.apache.spark.rpc.netty.NettyRpcEnv.deserialize(NettyRpcEnv.scala:313) ~[spark-core_2.10-1.6.0-cdh5.12.0.jar:1.6.0-cdh5.12.0]
>       at org.apache.spark.rpc.netty.NettyRpcEnv$$anonfun$deserialize$1.apply(NettyRpcEnv.scala:260) ~[spark-core_2.10-1.6.0-cdh5.12.0.jar:1.6.0-cdh5.12.0]
>       at scala.util.DynamicVariable.withValue(DynamicVariable.scala:57) ~[correctedViewershipUserProfile-1.14-SNAPSHOT-jar-with-dependencies.jar:na]
>       at org.apache.spark.rpc.netty.NettyRpcEnv.deserialize(NettyRpcEnv.scala:259) ~[spark-core_2.10-1.6.0-cdh5.12.0.jar:1.6.0-cdh5.12.0]
>       at org.apache.spark.rpc.netty.NettyRpcHandler.internalReceive(NettyRpcEnv.scala:590) ~[spark-core_2.10-1.6.0-cdh5.12.0.jar:1.6.0-cdh5.12.0]
>       at org.apache.spark.rpc.netty.NettyRpcHandler.receive(NettyRpcEnv.scala:572) ~[spark-core_2.10-1.6.0-cdh5.12.0.jar:1.6.0-cdh5.12.0]
>       at org.apache.spark.network.sasl.SaslRpcHandler.receive(SaslRpcHandler.java:80) ~[spark-network-common_2.10-1.6.0-cdh5.12.0.jar:1.6.0-cdh5.12.0]
>       at org.apache.spark.network.server.TransportRequestHandler.processRpcRequest(TransportRequestHandler.java:154) [spark-network-common_2.10-1.6.0-cdh5.12.0.jar:1.6.0-cdh5.12.0]
>       at org.apache.spark.network.server.TransportRequestHandler.handle(TransportRequestHandler.java:102) [spark-network-common_2.10-1.6.0-cdh5.12.0.jar:1.6.0-cdh5.12.0]
>       at org.apache.spark.network.server.TransportChannelHandler.channelRead0(TransportChannelHandler.java:104) [spark-network-common_2.10-1.6.0-cdh5.12.0.jar:1.6.0-cdh5.12.0]
>       at org.apache.spark.network.server.TransportChannelHandler.channelRead0(TransportChannelHandler.java:51) [spark-network-common_2.10-1.6.0-cdh5.12.0.jar:1.6.0-cdh5.12.0]

Answer (score 0):

Do you use shadow Jar ?
You can try exclude scala-library from kafka_2.10.